# Multiple Insert Statement blocking small one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say I have one `insert` statement going where the values come from a `select` statement from another table. Therefore, many records are inserted at once.  I have another process that just needs to insert a single record. How can I get SQL Server to let the single insert statement execute in a more timely manner? In my observations, the single one gets blocked for quite some time while the multiple insert runs. It would good if the single could "slip in". I tried adding `WITH (ROWLOCK)` on the inserts.

Comment: Can you control the timing of those 2 processes to start them in the proper order? Otherwise, it would be best to let things work as they are.

Comment: The code is just something like
INSERT INTO TABLE A SELECT * FROM TABLE B   

and a second process is doing something like
INSERT INTO TABLE A VALUES(val1, vale2) etc.

The single insert is getting blocked by the table based insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the bulk insertion is escalating to table locks. You can potentially reduce table locks by changing the table DDL to [`LOCK_ESCALATION=DISABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx), although this could degrade the bulk insert performance.

An alternative is to rewrite the bulk `INSERT` / `SELECT INTO` to insert in batches such that it never holds more than [5000 locks at a time.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). This would however change the scope of each unit of work, as you will now commit after each smaller batch, which may not be desirable.

Comment: I wound up breaking into batches. That was the only way that other processes could insert records in a timely manner.